# In Coldfusion how do insert multiple checkbox values with the same name into a database?

Tags: forms, loops, checkbox, coldfusion

So I am wanting to do this:

- Start Loop to check for each checkbox in a form checked called "tags"
- Insert into database
- End Loop

Comment: Depends on how they should be stored in the database.

Comment: Generally though it's a good idea to avoid actually placing a query inside of a loop.

Comment: The form will give you a comma-delimited list of the checkbox values that have been checked.     So the value of form.tags will be something like "1,2,8,11"  and you can just loop over that list to do what you like.

Comment: What's the part with which you are having difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple fields with same name, such is the case with checkboxes, are accessible by default in CF as a comma-delimited list. There is also a way to adjust CF to access these as an array which is important in situations where the the values could contain commas.

```
<!--- ensure any checkboxes were checked, otherwise field isn't passed --->
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "tags")>
    <cfloop list="#form.tags#" index="tag">
        <cfquery datasource="yourdsn">
            INSERT INTO TableName (
                ColumnName
            )
            VALUES (
                <cfqueryparam value="#tag#" />
            )
        </cfquery>
    </cfloop>
</cfif>
```

Of course the above is dependant on your specific need.

Comment: @mathin2000 I would not recommend looping around a `cfquery`. That will make a new connection for every record you want to insert. It would be MUCH more efficient to loop the values and then execute a single `cfquery` to insert the multiple values.

Comment: @Shawn connections are maintained by default in CF fyi

Comment: @DanRoberts Even when the query value changes? I'll look at that, that's very likely something I forgot. Regardless, if you take it down to the SQL level, it's still creating a new database transaction for each `INSERT`, which you wouldn't want to do. A single `INSERT` with bulk values would be cleaner.